# how to write trigger for insert, update

Tags: sql

I am trying to write trigger for insert,update code below

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tg_tbl_demographic_details_purple] 
ON [dbo].[tbl_demographic_details]
FOR  INSERT,update

AS
BEGIN

declare @purple_sc varchar(10),@id varchar(10),@name varchar(30)

set @purple_sc= (select Purple from tbl_demographic_details where sno=@@IDENTITY )

if update(Purple)--purle is column name if this column is update below if loop executed 
begin
    if (@purple_sc > 105)
    begin

        set @id= (select ID from tbl_demographic_details where sno=@@IDENTITY )
        set @name= (select name from tbl_demographic_details where sno=@@IDENTITY )

        update tbl_list_purple_flag set Score=@purple_sc,Id=@id,Name=@name where date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), SYSDATETIME(), 10) 
    end
end

if (@purple_sc > 105)
begin
    set @id= (select ID from tbl_demographic_details where sno=@@IDENTITY )
    set @name= (select name from tbl_demographic_details where sno=@@IDENTITY )

    insert into tbl_list_purple_flag (Score,Id,Name,Date) values(@purple_sc,@id,@name,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), SYSDATETIME(), 10))   
end

END
```

Problem is its inserting twice like below

```
Sno  Id     Name  Score  Date    
24   0107140000 sd    111    01-07-14    
25   NULL       NULL  111    01-07-14
```

What's wrong with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `FOR  INSERT,update` to `instead of insert, update` and it should work just fine.

Your trigger is happening *after* the insert/update is done, an instead of trigger doesn't let the insert/update happen at all.

You might have to separate the two triggers (ie. one for `instead of insert` and the other to `instead of update`) to make this work, just try it.

If this doesn't work, you should post what kind of SQL server you are using - I'm assuming MS SQL, where this should work.

Also, you should avoid using `@@IDENTITY`. It contains the last inserted identity value, which may be the value you expect, or not. Instead, you should use the `inserted` table you get in the trigger, which contains all of the inserted/updated rows that caused the trigger to... trigger.

For example, if you did an update of more than a single row at once, `@@IDENTITY` is only going to have the last one changed, and you will not do anythign about the ones before.

Also, it seems that you're creating a completely unnecessary amount of triggers - are you sure they are different enough that that's a good solution?

Comment: For an update trigger, `@@IDENTITY` will be worse than useless - `UPDATE` doesn't affect it. But your point is still relevant for multi-row inserts.